# getting JSONArrays with Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to get a JSONArray from a server but getting all kinds of errors. EDIT : tried adding all these imports.

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;


    public class VolleyFetcher extends AppCompatActivity
    {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://xxxxxx.json"; 

        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
                });

        queue.add(jsObjRequest);    
    }
```

My errors:

`Response cannot be resolved to a type`

`JSONArray cannot be resolved to a type`

`Syntax error on token "jsObjRequest", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token (//line : queue.add(jsObjRequest)`

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONObjectRequest` should be used if the result returned is a JSON Object.

If you're expecting to get a JSON Array back, you should use `JSONArrayRequest`. This request should be included in Volley's toolbox package.

The result request declaration should look like this:

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest("http://my.url.com/", new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response)
            {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed that, now it states
`The type new Response.ErrorListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Response.ErrorListener.onErrorResponse(VolleyError)` , which is weird since I did add that implementation..
and the error on queue.add(jsObjRequest) still appears..

Comment: I still get 
The type new Response.ErrorListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Response.ErrorListener.onErrorResponse(VolleyError)
for some reason

Comment: that's strange. could you have conflicting imports? try cleaning / restarting your IDE?

Comment: Tried that. Same thing..
by the way , another error I get is 

VolleyError cannot be resolved to a type

Regarding the imports , I've edited the post with all the imports I've added.

Comment: I've somehow fixed that..
Now I only have the error on 
`queue.add(jsObjRequest);  `
which is : `Syntax error on token "request", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token`